# Undefined reference to `_imp__apr_getopt_init@16'

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors

I have a library function that I am trying to link but the compiler throws a linker error by appending "(*imp*_)" prefix to the function name.

I don't understand why compiler prefixes the name of the function with "*imp*_" and I don't understand the underlying linker problem.

Comment: Please post more info about your platform/compiler. Is this helpful?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/12/14/301225.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the static vs dynamic linking problem.

Compiler will reference function as *impl*_+funcname if it thinks that the actual function will be placed in *dynamic* library. I.e. actual foobar implementation is in the dll and *impl*_foobar is kind of stub to make linker happy (address of foobar is not known on link stage and will be known only once your application loaded dll in runtime).

So, verify how exactly you should link to that library (usually libs come in both static and dynamic variants) and link to it according to that.

Comment: So, is there a way that I can instruct the compiler to not dynamically link to the method's definition and link as I direct it to?

Comment: I don't remember seeing something like this on per-method basis, but you can do this for specific lib. This should work for you. Play with project preferences in ui if you use VS or see docs/help for your linker on how to achieve this.

Comment: And another thing - if that is transitive (non-direct) dependency you are struggling with - you might not be able to fix it that easily. These kind of issues usually are tricky and rather hard to fix.

If that is the case I strongly recommend you to take your time and get solid understanding how linking in your toolchain works and how your dependencies are meant to link.